# using a for loop to assign values to elements in an array in simple pseudocode

Tags: pseudocode

```
declare numbers[5]

numbers[0]= "10"
numbers[1]= "20"
numbers[2]= "30"
numbers[3]= "40"
numbers[4]= "50"
```

How would I, using a for loop, populate the above array without having 5 individual statements that assign values to each element in the array?

I have tried:

```
declare numbers[5]

for count = 0 to 4

    display "enter value"
    get numbers[count]

endfor
```

This allows me to manually assign the values through running the code,
is there a way to run the array with a for loop that automatically assigns the values 10,20,30,40 and 50 to each element in the array?

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is to generate your array and then iterate an amount of times equal to your array and fill in a value that can be calculated based on the iterator (or the position of the array, as they are equivalent).

```
    declare numbers[5]
    for int i=1; ++i; i < 6
    numbers[i] = (i * 10)
```

Comment: You're welcome - If you're done and don't need more help, don't forget to accept the answer that way others know not to come in and solve it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare number[5]
for i = 0 to 4
    numbers [ i ] = 10 + i*10
endfor
```